# OFF_HEAP rdd was removed automatically by Tachyon, after the spark job done

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, alluxio

I run a spark application, it uses a StorageLevel.OFF_HEAP to persist a rdd(my tachyon and spark are both in local mode).

like this:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("FILE_PATH/test-lines-1")
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).persist(StorageLevel.OFF_HEAP)
val counts = words.reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.collect.foreach(println)
...
sc.stop
```

when persist done, I can see my OFF_HEAP files from localhost:19999(tachyon's web UI), this is what i excepted.

But, after the spark application over(sc.stop, but tachyon is working), my blocks(OFF_HEAP rdd) were removed. And I can not find my files from localhost:19999. This is not what I want.
I think these files belong to Tachyon (not spark) after persist() method, they should not be removed.

so, who deleted my files, and when?
Is this the normal way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```
  saveAs[Text|Parquet|NewHadoopAPI]File()
```

This is the real "persistent" method you need.

Instead

```
persist()
```

is used for intermediate storage of RDD's: when the spark process ends they will be removed. Here is from the source code comments:

> - Set this RDD's storage level to persist its values across operations after the first time
>     it is computed.

The important phrase is ***across operations*** - that is as part of processing (only).